# parent node kill testcafe process

Tags: node.js, testing, process, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a small project with testcafe installed. The index.js export a function where I use createTestRunner utility of testcafe framework. If I run this file with node in my project all will be good. But if I use this project as external npm package (for example with npm link) The process where I' m running my app run also my testcafe module, but it is killed before waiting for the end of this process.

Comment: Please provide more details about the issue you faced. How does your function call `createTestRunner`? What does it return? How is it called outside of the npm package? How do you run your application?

So far, I can only assume that `await` might be missing somewhere in your code. First, `createTestRunner` returns a promise. After that, we call the `.then` method. It returns another promise, and so on. Does your application wait for the final one?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your runner something like the snippet below, in which testcafe is not killed before it's terminated successfully.

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
class TestcafeRunner {
    constructor(browser, out, src, rType, count, headless, pn, now) {
        this.port1 = pn;
        this.port2 = ++pn;
    }

    async run() {           
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            let testcafe = null;
            resolve({failedNrOfTests: await createTestCafe('localhost', this.port1, this.port2)
                .then(async tc => {
                    testcafe = tc;
                    return await testcafe
                        .createRunner()
                        .src(yourTestSrcFiles)
                        .browsers(this.browser)
                        .reporter(config)
                        .run();
                })
});
        })
    }
}
```